# Make a UIButton background image larger than frame

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm trying to make a `UIButton` with a background image where the image is larger than the button frame.

The problem is, the `UIButton` automatically scales the image to fit and haven't found a way to change the behavior.

Am I missing something obvious or is it time to make a custom button?

Comment: Why not just make the button frame the size of the image?

Comment: Here's an analogy for an answer. Image puzzle pieces. They aren't square and fit together perfectly, but you can't very well have the button be a square around the outer most points of the piece or you'll wind up with buttons that overlap. You'd want you button to be the main body of the piece and have the little odd bits just hang off the edge.

Comment: now I understand better...just overlay an 'invisible' button on top of a `UIImageView` showing your larger image.  The button can be the appropriate size to keep it from overlaying/interfering with other buttons.

Comment: Right. I can fairly easily sub-class `UIButton` and load up my own XIB which has `UIButton` placed on top of an `UIImageView` either have the `UIImageView` bigger or just turn off clipping and set the image to `center`, but this feels like something people would use a lot and I don't want build a wheel because I'm to dense to notice the one sitting in front of me.

Comment: take a look at `imageEdgeInsets` on the button.  Setting the top/left/bottom/right values of the `UIEdgeInset` to negative values should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: `imageEdgeInsets` are for the content image, not the background image. And it still clips at the edge of the `UIButton` frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer to this one is. Not possible through existing interface on `UIButton`.

The simplest way to implement seems to be using a custom sub class of `UIButton` and creating a `UIImageView` with the same frame as the `UIButton`, turn off clipping and scaling and then just capture all the `setBackground` methods and capture state changes to handle "normal" button interaction changing the background images.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass UIButton and override the

```
- (CGRect)backgroundRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
```

method so it returns the size you want.

TIP: Use this method to center your background as well.